AMAZON RDS database: Note: Access denied for user 'rdsadmin'@'localhost'
I continuously receive the following notes on inside my RDS database (I started to receive them suddenly on October 25, 2024)and I continue to receive them non-stop every 15 seconds. The errors appear underneath error/mysql-error-running.log
2024-10-31T12:02:52.411064Z 70945385 [Note] [MY-010926] [Server] Access denied for user 'rdsadmin'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
2024-10-31T12:03:07.411634Z 70946159 [Note] [MY-010926] [Server] Access denied for user 'rdsadmin'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
2024-10-31T12:03:22.412239Z 70947041 [Note] [MY-010926] [Server] Access denied for user 'rdsadmin'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
2024-10-31T12:03:37.411829Z 70948076 [Note] [MY-010926] [Server] Access denied for user 'rdsadmin'@'localhost' (using password: NO)


You should check all your services that connected to this rds to find clues.
And change localhost to your rds endpoint in that service if you still want to connect.
For easy tracking you could add a new user to use on that service.

The rdsadmin user is a user which is created by AWS, right?
I don't have a connection problem at the time being. But I still see this note. What do you mean by adding a new user to that service?

Assume you have another service that connect to this RDS, you should create a new user for it then you can manage it using admin account inside Mysql. Don't use admin credential in your service.
